# Bug with "Top Questions" overflow

Tags: bug, design, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question column too narrow in Firefox](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1479/question-column-too-narrow-in-firefox)

The "Top Questions" list contained in `<div id="question-mini-list">` has setting overflow to auto. With my Firefox set to have minimum font size to 16 (*Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced > Minimum font size*), it makes this list clipped, so almost unreadable. A scroll-bar is added at the bottom of the page, but it's really not convenient. Here's a screen-shot to illustrate the bug:

[image]

This bug occurs with any tab of the "Top Questions" list (active, featured, hot, week, month).

More information: if I comment the following CSS property:

```
#question-mini-list {overflow: auto;}
```

I don't have the bug.

Comment: ...or setting the `<hr />` to `clear: both;` .